# I'm trying to use CNN with data that aren't images

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

The code being used is the CNN from http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#lenet but i'm having problems to understand what i need to change in order to accept other types of data. The file that i used has the same format of the MNIST but much smaller, this is the data being used https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris

These are the two parts that i changed:

Batch_size, nkers, n_epocchs

```
def evaluate_lenet5(learning_rate=0.1, n_epochs=1000, nkerns=[3, 4], batch_size=5):
```

All parameters of the layers

```
layer0_input = x.reshape((batch_size, 1, 2, 2))

layer0 = LeNetConvPoolLayer(rng, input=layer0_input, image_shape=(batch_size, 1, 2, 2), filter_shape=(nkerns[0], 1, 1, 1), poolsize=(2, 2))

layer1 = LeNetConvPoolLayer(rng, input=layer0.output, image_shape=(batch_size, nkerns[0], 2, 2), filter_shape=(nkerns[1], nkerns[0], 1, 1), poolsize=(2, 2))

layer2_input = layer1.output.flatten(2)

layer2 = HiddenLayer(rng, input=layer2_input, n_in=nkerns[1], n_out=15, activation=T.tanh)

layer3 = LogisticRegression(input=layer2.output, n_in=15, n_out=3)
```

When i execute this code i get this error:

```
In [4]: %run test_convolutional_mlp.py
... loading data
... building the model
... training
training @ iter =  0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/media/HD Usuario/DeepLearning/Iris Data/test_convolutional_mlp.py in <module>()
    172 
    173 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 174     evaluate_lenet5()
    175 
    176 

/media/HD Usuario/DeepLearning/Iris Data/test_convolutional_mlp.py in evaluate_lenet5(learning_rate, n_epochs, nkerns, batch_size)
    128             if iter % 100 == 0:
    129                 print 'training @ iter = ', iter
--> 130             cost_ij = train_model(minibatch_index)
    131 
    132             if (iter + 1) % validation_frequency == 0:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    586                     # For the CVM

    587                     gof.vm.raise_with_op(self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
--> 588                                          self.fn.thunks[self.fn.position_of_error])
    589                 else:
    590                     # For the c linker


/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    577         t0_fn = time.time()
    578         try:
--> 579             outputs = self.fn()
    580         except Exception:
    581             if hasattr(self.fn, 'position_of_error'):

ValueError: the number of rows in the image (1) at run time is different than at build time (2) for the ConvOp.
Apply node that caused the error: ConvOp{('imshp', (3, 2, 2)),('kshp', (1, 1)),('nkern', 4),('bsize', 5),('dx', 1),('dy', 1),('out_mode', 'valid'),('unroll_batch', 5),('unroll_kern', 2),('unroll_patch', False),('imshp_logical', (3, 2, 2)),('kshp_logical', (1, 1)),('kshp_logical_top_aligned', True)}(Elemwise{Composite{[tanh(add(i0, i1))]}}.0, <TensorType(float64, 4D)>)
Inputs shapes: [(5, 3, 1, 1), (4, 3, 1, 1)]
Inputs strides: [(24, 8, 8, 8), (24, 8, 8, 8)]
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, 4D), TensorType(float64, 4D)]
Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint of this apply node.
```

Probably the answer is really easy but i'm around a week looking this code and nothing pops in my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C in CNN stands for convolution. In order to perform a convolution you need variables that taken together form some sort of spatial/temporal/in any way continuous extent, on which a group structure holds, such as translation in space, translation in time, rotations, or something more exotic. This is not the case for the data you are working with, so using a CNN does not make much sense. (That doesn't stop you from trying to arrange the variables in a 2D space and to see what comes out, but it doesn't seem at all useful.) If you want to do NNs, stick to fully connected ones and start by evaluating logistic regression.

Comment: Sorry for the late a answer and thanks for your answer, as you have noticed it english isn't my native language and i can't get this part "variables that taken together form some sort of spatial/temporal/in any way continuous extent, on which a group structure holds".
And other thing that i forgot to mention is that my objective of doing this is to what needed to be changed on the code for later apply on numeric values that the kinect gives and other collect by hand from peoples, there are 81 atributtes can this be used on a CNN?

Comment: Your data need to have structure that lends itself to convolution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). The least necessary is group structure.